# Rails - set default value for form text_field with current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to default my contact form email field to the current_user.email value. If there's no current_user, then a simple input field should show. I tried the below which works, but if there's no current_user, the the textfield doesn't show.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Email</label> 
  <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: 'form-control', value:current_user.email if current_user  %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Its not showing because the if statement applies to the whole text-field, not just the value attribute.  This will work:

```
<% if current_user %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: 'form-control', value:current_user.email  %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: 'form-control'%>
<% end %>
```

However, if you are using devise, it comoes with a helper method that is generally better to user than current_user.  I think your code should be this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: 'form-control', value:current_user.email %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: 'form-control'%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So, I have to do for each form field? I was hoping for a shortcut of shorter method...

Comment: I believe you need to remove 'if current_user' in 'value:current_user.email if current_user' since you already tested for current_user

Answer (score 6):

http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

```
<%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: 'form-control', value: current_user.try(:email)  %>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: 'form-control', value: current_user.try(:email)  %>
```

on old versions

```
    <%= form.text_field :email, :value=> current_user.try(:email),:class=>"form-control"%>
```

or just

```
<%= text_field(:doc, :email, {:value=>current_user.try(:email),:class=>"form-control"})%>
```

Comment: This only echoes a [much older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35933152) to add obsolete syntax.